# Ctypes malloc for image data

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to wrap the following c function using ctypes:

```cpp
    #define MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH 1024
    #define MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT 1024
    UFE_STATUS ufe_res;
    char szFileName[256];
    unsigned char* pImage;
    int nWidth;
    int nHeight;

    // Get file name from user, szFileName

    // Allocate image buffer
    pImage = (unsigned char*)malloc(MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH, MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
    ufe_res = UFE_LoadImageFromBMPFile(szFileName, pImage, &nWidth, &nHeight);
```

However, I do not know, how to allocate memory in python using ctypes like this:

> ```
> pImage = (unsigned char*)malloc(MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH, MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
> ```

Can someone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will allocate a `char` array.  `c_char * N` creates a 1-dimensional array of size N:

```
image = (c_char * (MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH * MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT))()
```

Note that the parentheses matter:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> x=10
>>> y=20
>>> ctypes.c_char * x * y                      # 2D char[y][x] equivalent type
<class '__main__.c_char_Array_10_Array_20'>    # note order of x and y above
>>> ctypes.c_char * (x * y)                    # 1D char[x*y] equivalent type
<class '__main__.c_char_Array_200'>
>>> (ctypes.c_char * (x*y))()                  # instance of char[x*y] array.
<__main__.c_char_Array_200 object at 0x0000014CBB9AF848>
>>> i = (ctypes.c_char * x * y)()              # instance of 2D char[y][x] array.
>>> i[19]                                      # first dimension is y
<__main__.c_char_Array_10 object at 0x0000014CBB9AF848>
>>> i[19][9]                                   # 2nd dimension is x
b'\x00'
```

The above can create arrays of any type.  If you need `c_char` or `c_wchar` arrays, you can use:

```
>>> ctypes.create_string_buffer(x * y)
<__main__.c_char_Array_200 object at 0x0000014CBB9AF9C8>
>>> ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(x * y)
<ctypes.c_wchar_Array_200 object at 0x0000014CBB9AF848>
```